# Laravel: Says input required when it's there?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to code a login system in Laravel and it keeps telling me the text box is required. I've added the textbox, rechecked the names are correct and I've made sure I enter text on submit of the form it belows to.

It keeps saying "The credentials.username field is required.", if I remove the required from the validation it will say it for password too.

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <div id="login-columns">
        <div id="login-column-1">
            <label for="credentials-email">Username</label> 
            <input id="credentials-email" name="credentials.username" tabindex="2" type="text"> 
            <input id="credentials-remember-me" name="_login_remember_me" tabindex="5" type="checkbox"> 
            <label class="sub-label" for="credentials-remember-me">Keep me logged in</label>
        </div>
        <div id="login-column-2">
            <label for="credentials-password">Password</label> 
            <input id="credentials-password" name="credentials.password" tabindex="3" type="password">
        </div>
        <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div id="login-column-3">
            <input style="margin: -10000px; position: absolute;" type="submit" value="Login"> <a class="button" href="#" id="credentials-submit" tabindex="4"><b></b><span>Login</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="login-column-4">
            888 Online
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
public function onPost(Request $request) 
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'credentials.username' => 'required|exists:users',
        'credentials.password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ( $validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator->messages());
    }
    else {
        if (!Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->input('credentials.username'), 'password' => $request->input('credentials-password')])) {
            return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Failed Authentication')->withColor('danger');
        }
        else {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->save();

            return Redirect::to('/home');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are seeing is that Laravel treats 'credentials.username' as a "Nested Attribute".  For instance if you are rendering a view 'layout.head'  it will automatically look for the file head.blade.php inside the layout folder.

I think in this case it's assuming you are passing it an array like:

```
<input id="credentials-email" name="credentials[username]" tabindex="2" type="text"> 

<input id="credentials-password" name="credentials[password]" tabindex="3" type="password">
```

Have you tried:

```
<input id="credentials-email" name="credentials_username" tabindex="2" type="text"> 

<input id="credentials-password" name="credentials_password" tabindex="3" type="password">
```

There is a very brief mention of nested attributes on the Laravel validation documentation page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

Answer (score 0):

Don't use dot inside name input.

Replace `credentials.username` by `credentials_username`.

Or even better, just `username`.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel validation dot(.) Represent array of items. In this case you need to modify your input field name like this `<input name="credentials[username]"> <input name="credentials[password]">`